# Suitescript 2.0 record.load either Lead or Prospect

Tags: netsuite, suitescript

I created a user event script that updates a lead custom field from a new phone call record on afterSubmit. It loads the customer from the id of the entity id on the phone call event. It works fine, but it loads a lead record only. How do I fine tune this script to get the entity type and then use that to determine which record type to load?

```
function afterSubmit(context) {
                var phoneRec = context.newRecord;
                var checkbox1 = phoneRec.getValue({
                    fieldId: 'custevent_field1'
                });
                var checkbox2 = phoneRec.getValue({
                    fieldId: 'custevent_field2'
                });

                var custId = phoneRec.getValue({
                    fieldId: 'company'
                });

                if(custId && checkbox1 == true) {
                    var loadedcust = record.load({
                        type : record.Type.LEAD,
                        id : custId});
                        loadedcust.setValue({
                            fieldId:'custentity_filed1',
                            value: true });
                            loadedcust.save();
                }

                if(custId && checkbox2 == true) {
                    var loadedcust = record.load({
                        type : record.Type.LEAD,
                        id : custId});
                        loadedcust.setValue({
                            fieldId:'custentity_field2',
                            value: true });
                            loadedcust.save();
                }
        }

        return {afterSubmit}
```

Not sure how to pull more entity information from just the id value. Any insight will help.

Comment: I may have realized that I can use record.Type.CUSTOMER. Is that correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you should be able to use just customer.

Also unless your values are exclusive you can also do the following to make the return quicker:

```js
define(['N/record',...], function(record,...){ // include record module in your define

function afterSubmit(context) {
    var phoneRec = context.newRecord;
    var checkbox1 = phoneRec.getValue({
        fieldId: 'custevent_field1'
    });
    var checkbox2 = phoneRec.getValue({
        fieldId: 'custevent_field2'
    });

    var custId = phoneRec.getValue({
        fieldId: 'company'
    });

    var updates = {};
    var anyUpdate = false;

    if(custId && checkbox1 == true) {
        updates.custentity_filed1 = true; //not field1?
        anyUpdate = true;
    }

    if(custId && checkbox2 == true) {
        updates.custentity_field2 = true;
        anyUpdate = true;
    }

    if(anyUpdate){ //single update. No need to load record twice nor submit it twice.
        record.submitFields({
            type:'customer',
            id:custId,
            values:updates
        })
    }

}

return {afterSubmit}
}
```

Comment: That's a great shortcut! I'm keeping that for reference next time. Thank you so much for looking at this!